# bxslider with modal popup + safari

Tags: safari, modal-dialog, bxslider

If you go there : http://winkstrategies.com/#clients

and you click on the first logo (Les Aliments SRC) you will see the bxslider working, if you close the popup and click back on the same logo the bxslider not seem to be working. Does someone have an idea?

Second problem if you look the same page with safari and click the first logo you will see the 2 slides overlapping each other? in firefox it's ok... what is causing this?

Thanks